# How to override Primefaces extension exporter

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Can anyone explain how to override the Primefaces extension's exporter. I want to customize the PDFexporter.But dont know which all files has to be kept in workarea and which path.I did create a META-INF folder under resources folder and that a folder named as services.Inside that created a file named as

`org.primefaces.extensions.component.exporter.ExporterFactory` containg a one line text as `common.util.CustomExporter` which is the name of the custom exporter class I wanted to make use of.

In that class I extended the `exportValue()` method and wrote my own code.
However, while I am trying to generate the PDF I am getting the following error

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.primefaces.extensions.component.exporter.ExporterFactory: Provider common.util.CustomExporter could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast common.util.CustomExporter to org.primefaces.extensions.component.exporter.ExporterFactory
```

So please explain where I am going wrong or what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces extension exporter allows you to export to pdf and customize some settings but is very limited, to generate PDF using default values ​​gives itext. I had the same problem as you and the solution for me was to manipulate the pdf in pre and postProcessor methods. See this page, maybe can help you:
[change default format dataExporter in Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201157/change-default-format-dataexporter-in-primefaces)

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see it tries to convert yout Exporter to ExporterFactory. You need to extend ExportFactory in which you, in case of type PDF, instantiate your own PDFExporter.