# Primefaces DataExporter Set Table Columns Width

Tags: primefaces, pdf-generation, primefaces-dataexporter

I have a Primefaces DataGrid that I export whith Primefaces DataExporter but I can't figure out how to resize the columns.

I added a preporcessor

```
<p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="cars" preProcessor="#{customizedDocumentsView.preProcessPDF}" />
```

And this is the code in my bean

```
public void preProcessPDF(Object document) {
        Document pdf = (Document) document;
        pdf.open();
        pdf.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);

        //I need to do something like that
        //PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
        //float[] columnWidths = new float[] {10f, 20f, 30f, 10f};
        //table.setWidths(columnWidths);
    }
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I inherited project with many already existing *exporters* with already set *options* tags so I needed to find solution that will keep all of them intact.

I got an idea from this accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201157/change-default-format-dataexporter-in-primefaces).

My solution sets column widths via *options* tag of *p:dataExporter* so there is no need for pre/post processing. I tested it using Primefaces ver 4.x and up.

**Step by step procedure:**

1. Create new package
   `org.primefaces.component.export`
   inside your project.
2. From Primefaces git repository fully copy following classes
   [ExporterOptions](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/export/ExporterOptions.java) ,[PDFOptions](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/export/PDFOptions.java), [Exportedfactory](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/export/ExporterFactory.java) and [PDFExporter](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/export/PDFExporter.java)
   into newly created package.
3. In *ExporterOptions* add
   `public float[] getColumnWidths();`
4. In *PDFOptions* add 
   `float[] columnWidths;`
   and add getter and setter.
5. In *ExporterFactory* modify line 
   `exporter = new PdfExporter();` to  `exporter = new CustomPdfExporter();`
6. Rename *PDFExporter* class to *CustomPDFExporter* and keep just following *export* method fully

   ```
   public void export(FacesContext context, DataTable table, String filename, boolean pageOnly, boolean selectionOnly, String encodingType,MethodExpression preProcessor, MethodExpression postProcessor, ExporterOptions options) throws IOException
   ```

Delete code from other *export* methods but keep declarations.

7. Inside *CustomPDFExporter* add 2 lines in *ExportPdfTable* method

   ```
   protected PdfPTable exportPDFTable(FacesContext context, DataTable table, boolean pageOnly, boolean selectionOnly, String encoding) throws DocumentException {
      int columnsCount = getColumnsCount(table);
      PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(columnsCount);
      this.cellFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES, encoding);
      this.facetFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES, encoding, Font.DEFAULTSIZE, Font.BOLD);

       if (this.expOptions != null) {
           applyFacetOptions(this.expOptions);
           applyCellOptions(this.expOptions);
           //line 1
           //sets columns column relative widths to iText PdfTable object
           pdfTable.setWidths(this.expOptions.getColumnWidths());
           //line 2
           //decreases page margins comparing to original 'Primefaces' layout
           pdfTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
       }

       //....
   ```

   }
8. Now you are ready to go managed bean and add pdf option. For example

   ```
   pdfOpt = new PDFOptions(); //add getter and setter too
   pdfOpt.setFacetBgColor("#F88017");
   ...
   //if, for example, your PDF table has 4 columns
   //1st column will occupy 10% of table's horizontal width,...3rd - 20%, 4th - 60% 
   float[] columnWidths = new float[]{0.1f, 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.6f};
   pdfOpt.setColumnWidths(columnWidths);
   ...
   ```
9. Finally your `p:dataExporter` component should look like this

   ```
   <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="cars" options="#{customizedDocumentsView.pdfOpt}"/>
   ```

This solution using [PF showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/customizedDocuments.xhtml) produces following result
[image]

**Suggestion for extending this solution:**

Primefaces exporter uses iText ver 2.1.7. with old but still powerful API.
For example, in *ExporterOptions* in step 1. you can add

```
public int[] getColumnWidths();
```

to set **absolute** column widths
or you can set any other option driven by your project requirements.