# Primefaces Datatable pdf export custom Column width

Tags: java, primefaces

i want to change column width when i export my datatable with primefaces exporter - for example 5 columns - 35%  35%  10% 10% 10% width  but there is no option for that, could someone please post a possibly workaround?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743148/primefaces-dataexporter-set-table-columns-width) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: i tried but it doesnt work: Nullpointer Exception - com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.setWidths(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:?]

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.
Create a custom style in a css file:

```
.column30 {
    width: 30px !important;
    max-width: 30px;
}
```

Then use the style in column

```
 <p:column headerText="example header" styleClass="column30">
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with column width in the pdf after export